# how to call a function with ether through web3

Tags: web3js

I'm writing a simple DApp in webpack sample(metacoin) in truffle,there is a function that need to call with 2 ether and 1 input parameter. And my question is how to call that function in the index.js,should i use xx.methods.function().send(from:,value:)?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to call a function with 2 ether and 1 input parameter, the right way of doing this will be:

```
let valueToSend = 2 * 10^18
contractInstance.functionName(
    inputParameter,
    { 
        from: accountFromWhichTxIsInvoked,
        value: valueToSend
    }
)
```

**Note: ->**
**1 ether = 1 * 10^18**